# How To Make Story Preview (ImageView , label, or other content) like instagram,facebook or Airbnb?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to build image and view preview like facebook Instagram story where a certain time after time content will change. I got some API which does not fulfill my requirement like [Instagram_Stories](https://github.com/drawRect/Instagram_Stories/tree/Swift-v4.2) is there any other API? how can I make it using UIPageViewController or ScrollZView.I tried collectionView with ScrollToItem their problem is when finishing all image and back to first image its give right to left transition but I need always forward transition

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [carousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) to create paging effect like instagram stories.